# How do people write in their status "continue reading"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I want to know how people write in their status "continue reading" at the end, which is actually a link to their page?

Answer (score 4):

The "*continue reading*" is not placed there by the person. If the content of a post is too large, facebook will automatically minimize it, place the "*continue reading*" link at the end, and of course, link it to the whole posting. The link actually brings up the post not the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

To Create a customized link in Facebook you have to take just three steps:

1. You need to have a Facebook page id (the page you want to open)
2. Your post text
3. A shortcode as shown below

   ```
   @[Your Page Id:0] Your Post Text  @@[0:[Your Page Id:1:continue reading…]]
   ```

Find your pageId and replace the text "Your Page Id" in the shortcode above.

Note: This trick only works in the mobile version of Facebook.